# Cannot write a right script for email alerts from google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Try to write a script that will send the email alerts when a specific cell value appears. I have already put the following code:

```
function sendEmailAlert(w) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var cellValue = ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
var getColumn = ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getColumn();
var sheetname = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var Toemail = 'xxxxxxx@xxxxx.com';
var subject = 'xxxxxxx';
var body = 'The status was updated in - ' + sheetname + ' by - ' + user + ' Now the status in '+ cellValue + ' is ' +ss.getActiveCell().getValue()+ ' check file- ' + ss.getUrl();
if (ss.getActiveCell().getValue() == "Accepted" && getColumn == 15 && w.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Analysis") {
MailApp.sendEmail(Toemail, subject, body);
}
}
```

This works only when you make a change in the certain cell manually. If the cell contains the formula that makes the cell to be updated automatically, the script does not send any alerts when a specific cell value appears.

For example

My trigger is number 30. When I type 30 in the cell the script send me an alert message. But when a formula is applied in this cell like =DAYS(A1; A2) where A1 = 10/6/2020 and A2 = 9/6/2020 the script doesn’t send me anything.

Please help me to solve this problem. Hope the issue is clear. Any questions let me know down below

P.S.
I am not a programmer so please add comments to your code to explain the code rows actions

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions

Answer (score 0):

The reason your trigger is not triggering is because `onEdit()` requires the edit of the cell to be made by a **user**. Since you are changing the value of the cell using a formula, the trigger *won't fire*.

You might want to rethink your code and/or choose other methods to trigger the sending of the email.

You can, for example, use a time driven trigger which runs at a time chosen by you and checks if any changes have been made to the cell and send the email. Even though, the change won't be notified as quick as the `onEdit()`, it's an option since you plan on using formulas for your script.

#### Reference

- [Simple Triggers Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers);
- [Time Driven Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).